# IBM Rational DOORS - should I deploy it myself, or is there something more appropriate?

Tags: language-agnostic, ibm-doors

I'm inheriting a project that has, until now, had all its artifacts maintained in CVS and FogBugz. There's a ton of old and new documentation in MS Office format that needs to be reconciled.

I've seen some presentations on IBM Rational DOORS and think it would solve the lack of traceability across all these different documents and systems. My (possibly incorrect) understanding is that I could, for example, highlight a phrase in a Word document and mark that as a requirement, then create bi-directional links between that phrase and other artifacts, such as tasks in a bug-tracking system or entries in the changelog and user guide, to show that the requirement has been satisfied.

Unfortunately, if I want to use DOORS, I would probably have to install and maintain it myself. I found an open-source product for requirements management called [rmtoo](http://rmtoo.florath.net), but it looks like it would require me to rewrite all the documents document into a bunch of specially-formatted text files--which, for me, defeats the whole purpose. If DOORs is overkill, are there any low-overhead alternatives to DOORS?

Comment: Sounds too heavyweight to me.  It's what I've found to be true of all IBM products: clumsy, heavy, burdensome.  I don't believe it'll deliver on your expectations, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2022:** As a commenter rightly pointed out, the answer is dated due to changes in the tool ecosystem.

One of my frustrations is that there are many expensive tools (the main players are DOORS Next, Jama Connect, Codebeamer and Polarion).

For developers with a low budget, I often recommend [R4J, which is a Jira Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213064/r4j-requirements-management-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=cloud). I find the installation and configuration process a little cumbersome, but other than that, it provides basic functions, especially traceability. As of this writing, it was $100/year for up to 10 people.

## Original Answer

Do I understand correctly that you're trying to trace elements in DOORS, Word, Tracker-entry, etc.?  I don't think what you saw is possible with DOORS out of the box.  I think you need a tool like agosense for that, and tons of customization for adapters to the tools you need.  If you really want to know, I'd talk to an IBM Sales Rep.  But a DOORS-based solution will be really expensive.

It's unclear from your description how much control you have over the tool chain.  If you have full control and are looking for a cheap solution, you may want to check out something like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).  It's free and integrates bug tracking and Wiki (so essentially, for this to work you'd have to migrate your documentation from Office to the Wiki, and bugs from FogBugz to Trac - not sure whether your users will accept this, and it creates the same problem that rmtoo does).

Last, you could look into [Requisite Pro](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/reqpro/), an IBM product that is cheaper than DOORS.  It has the advantage that your requirements are managed directly in Word.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I moved everything to Trac, wouldn't I be right back where I am now, since FogBugz also has a wiki?

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the wiki to trace requirements; I'll have to play with it to see if it works better than what I'm doing now. Requisite Pro looks more along the lines of what I want, if there's an easy workaround for managing requirements documents that come as PowerPoint or Excel files.

Comment: Hi, the Requisite Pro points to a generic IBM product page nowadays. I doubt RP still exists. Contribution/Text should be edited.

Answer (score 3):

DOORS has bidirectional links, but they are only from "DOORS objects" in a "DOORS module" to another "DOORS object" in the same or another "DOORS module".

A DOORS object is a little like a row in a spreadsheet file, and a DOORS module is a little like a spreadsheet file.

You have to import all of your material into DOORS to work with it -- DOORS can't work with documents or generally communicate with the outside world very well. Importing and exporting Word documents into DOORS is incredibly breaky.

DOORS is really dated and limited.

[image: DOORS links]

Comment: Thanks for the nice summary.  Is there something else you know of which actually does what I want?

Comment: Thinking on this a bit more, have you considered GitHub? You don't need to use git to find it very useful. It's got an issue tracker, which could work well for requirements management, plus a wiki. If you used git you could store text as Markdown or DITA. You can store binary files like Word documents in there too.

Comment: The spreadsheet analogies are apropos: the rumor I heard was that DOORS started out as an Excel macro (run amuck).

Answer (score 0):

> If DOORs is overkill, are there any low-overhead alternatives to
> DOORS?

From experience, there are easily over 20 software tools (often ALM) that support the means of 'Requirements Engineering'.

Here is a short list:

- Siemens Polarion
- Cradle by 3SL
- Perforce ALM
- Jama
- Intland

...and further IBM DOORS NG "Next Gen", SAP, MKS/PTC Integrity with RE Addon, etc.

As for architecture, I'd recommend EA, Rhapsody, NoMagic, Visual Paradigm.

We have also projects that manage requirements with Confluence. Apparently Gitlab is planning a RE feature.

DOORS is still in actively in use depending on your industry. And there is good reason why.